# Interop.Excel localization and Range.Formula vs Formulalocal

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, excel-interop, formulas

I'm trying to generate excel file using Interop.Excel, but I have 2 localizations where I need to run my WPF application.

de-DE and en-US

For localization de-DE my program works fine(also DE MS Office are installed on my laptop), but when I try to run it on the en-US server then I have problems.

Here is a snippet of source code:

```
cell = "K" + rowCounter;          
Excel.Range ThisRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(cell, System.Type.Missing);
string myFunction;           

if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag == "de-DE")
   {
    myFunction = "=+WENN(I" + rowCounter + "<=J" + rowCounter + ";J" + rowCounter + "-I" + rowCounter + ";\"24:00\"+(J" + rowCounter + "-I" + rowCounter + "))";

    ThisRange.FormulaLocal = myFunction;         
   }
else
   {
    myFunction = "=+IF(I" + rowCounter + "<=J" + rowCounter + ";J" + rowCounter + "-I" + rowCounter + ";\"24:00\"+(J" + rowCounter + "-I" + rowCounter + "))";

    ThisRange.Formula = myFunction;
   }
```

And I always get kind of this exception:

Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Formula(Object value)

I also tried to change localization to de-DE when different localization is recognized - was not helpful.

Do you know please what might be wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Range.Formula` is always using formula notation in en_us. So function names are english but also the parameter delimiter is comma and not semi colon. Try `myFunction = "=+IF(I" + rowCounter + "<=J" + rowCounter + ",J" + rowCounter + "-I" + rowCounter + ",\"24:00\"+(J" + rowCounter + "-I" + rowCounter + "))";`. Btw. because of `Range.Formula` is always using formula notation in en_us, it is not necessary to distinguish the locale.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment from Axel, problem was in delimiter:

*Range.formula* requires **,**
*Range.formulalocal* requires **;**

I have fixed that in my source code and now it's working fine.